# Remove rows meeting specific condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix in MATLAB as follows:

```
A = [ 0, 0, 0;
      1, 2, 3;
      4, 2, 3;
      0, 0, 0;
      1, 3, 4 ];
```

I would like to remove the zeros from line 1 and line 4 so I can get the following matrix:

```
B = [ 1, 2, 3;
      4, 2, 3;
      1, 3, 4 ];
```

What I did is the following:

```
for i = 1:length(A)
    if (sum(A(i, :)) == 0)
        A(i, :) = [];
    end
end
```

I know that the problem is that `A` is changing in the size so that is the problem. Unfortunately, I cannot fix it. Could you please give me some hint.

Comment: Your approach will only work if you assume that you have no rows in your matrix that sum to zero.  Would your approach still work if we had the following matrix: `A = [-1 1 0; 1 0 -1];`?  Are you looking for removing rows that **sum** to zero or only contain zeroes?

Comment: I would like to remove the rows that are zeros. There is no negative value in my matrix. Thank you for your answer @rayryeng. I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kamtal's approach would work assuming that you have no rows that summed to zero.  To be safer, you should check to see if a row consists **only of zeroes**.  In other words, try doing this:

```
A(~any(A,2), :) = [];
```

[`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) checks to see if an array or matrix has any of its elements to be non-zero which outputs logical `true` and `false` otherwise.  If you use `any` over a matrix, you can specify whether you want to check for this over the rows or the columns in the second parameter of `any`.  In your case, you want to operate over the columns for each row, and so you'd specify the second parameter to be 2.

Because you want to check to see if any row consists of all zeroes, you would use `any` over the columns and check for the reverse.  As such, `any` would output logical `false` if **all of a row consisted only of zeroes**.  This is what we're looking for, but you want this to be `true` and not `false`, and hence we invert using `~` as the opposite is what we seek.

---

However, if you want to get your method working, you would not use a `for` loop, but a `while` loop instead as the index to access each row keeps changing.  As such, once you remove a row, you would not increment the index to access the next row, **until** you successfully find a row which doesn't sum to zero.  Remember, as you remove a row, the row that was just below it gets moved to the position that was removed, and so you would still check this same position for a row that didn't sum to zero.  You would move to the next row once you find a row that didn't sum to zero.

In other words, do this:

```
i = 1;
while i < length(A)
    if (sum(A(i, :)) == 0)
        A(i, :) = [];
        continue;
    end
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the rows with zero sum this might help,

```
A(sum(A,2)==0,:)=[];
```

As mentioned by @LuisMendo you can use

```
A(all(A,2)==0,:)=[];
```

depending on what criteria you have in mind.

Comment: To remove rows that contain all zeros: `A(all(A,2)==0,:)=[];`

Comment: @Kamtal Potential cavity.  What if you had a row that contained sums that cancelled to zero?  For example, what would happen if we had a matrix such that: `A = [-1 1 0; -1 0 1]`?

Comment: @LuisMendo - Oh wow.  I didn't see your comment!  Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks, actually the criteria of `sum=0` is in the question and I didn't change it.

Comment: @Kamtal - Ah.  Very true.  Perhaps the OP wanted to remove all rows of zeroes, but their initial approach says otherwise.  Still, a very good approach if that's what the OP is seeking.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Feliz año nuevo!

Comment: @rayryeng Bonne année pour vous aussi!